# Searching for keywords in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a dataframe with three columns of text blobs to search through, which can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/Seanny123/aed62e214493e2500b95e64fae98a0c8).

And three keywords that I want to identify in this text:

```
branches_of_sci = ['bio', 'chem', 'physics']
```

I've written the following code to identify the presence of these keywords:

```
dfq_col = ['Text A', 'Text B', 'Text C']

for branch in branches_of_sci:
    for col in dfq_col:
        temp_list = []
        for row in df[col]:
            if type(row) is not str:
                temp_list.append(False)
            elif type(row) is str:
                temp_list.append(row.find(branch)>0)
        df[branch] |= temp_list
```

This is the result of the data I linked to:

[image: table result]

I think the main problem here is that I'm using a for-loop when I should be using some sort of dataframe-specific function, but I'm not sure how to restructure the code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',') # copied data from the gist

branches_of_sci = ['bio', 'chem', 'physics']

for branch in branches_of_sci:
    df[branch] = df.astype(str).sum(axis=1).str.contains(branch)
```

In my limited experience, for loops are almost always wrong when using Pandas.  The primary benefit of Pandas is vectorization, so using the built-in methods is typically best.

Here is a breakdown of the main function:

1. `df[branch]`  creates a new dataframe column
2. `df.astype(str)` converts all of the dtypes in the dataframe to strings
3. `.sum(axis=1)` concatenates all dataframe columns horizontally (i.e. axis=1)
4. `.str.contains()` use built-in string search (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html))

Hopefully that helps.